# Storing combinations of an array in a list, contains N copies of last item added

Tags: java, arrays

My last question got closed for duplicate, but the question they referenced did not answer my question, it was too generic and for the wrong case.

I have some code which takes in a string array full of numbers. These are then shuffled into all possible unique combinations. This works fine provided the combinations are printed out. However, I am using this code as part of a bigger program and thus I need the combinations to be stored in a list. For some reason my attempts to store it in a list result in the entire list being populated with the final combination.

```
static List<String[]> combinations = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public static String[] combinationUtil(String arr[], String data[], int start, 
                            int end, int index, int r) { 
    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (index == r) 
    { 
        //this is supposed to add the combination to the list
        combinations.add(data);

        //for (int j=0; j<r; j++) 
         //   System.out.print(data[j]+" "); 
        //System.out.println(""); 
        return data; 
    } 
    //String[] test = combinations.get(2); 

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition 
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element 
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements 
    // at remaining positions 
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) { 
        data[index] = arr[i]; 
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
    } 

    return data;
} 

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r 
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil() 
public static void printCombination(String arr[], int n, int r) { 
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one 
    String data[]=new String[r]; 

    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]' 
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r); 
}
```

For example, when I pass in the following array it prints out the correct combinations but the list is filled entirely with [3.2, 3.3]

[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 2.0, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3]

How do I change this to store the combinations in a list?

Comment: _when I pass in the following array_ - Ok now we know `arr`, but what are the values of `n` and `r` to call `printCombination`?

Comment: r is the size of the combinations to be printed and n is the length of the array

Comment: And whiich values did you use in the stated example (resulting in [3.2, 3.3])? I would like to reproduce the described behaviour.

Comment: They are listed at the bottom of the question, string array [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 2.0, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3]

Comment: Hmm ... I'm trying this: `String[] arr = { "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "1.0", "1.1", "1.3", "2.0", "2.2", "2.3", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3" }; printCombination(arr, n, r);`  What I need to use as `n` and `r`?

Comment: n should be the length of the array and r can be set as 2

Comment: You dont need to pass array length as 2nd parameter, if you pass array as first, i think

Comment: Sure, but that still wont solve my issue

Comment: @eZ_Harry, your code works good: [3.2, 3.3] - is the last element of your combinations list, but its size is 78. So you need just simple method to print your combitation arrays (combinations list elements) to where you want

Comment: I know the code is getting the correct combinations and if I only wanted to print them that would be fine. However, I am trying to save these combinations to a list and it is not working.

Comment: oh, now i see what you are talking about, @eZ_Harry -- all values are same and equal [3.2, 3.3]. But if i print combination in the place of adding to collection (simple `System.out.print(", " + Arrays.toString(data))`), everything works -- if this cannot be your solution, then i will try to find the bug

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eZ_Harry, the solution is to use `clone()` of your combination array in this code row:

```
combinations.add(data.clone());
```

Comment: Because the same array object is added N times, so the last changes to array elements will be shown for every (exactly the identical) element of the list.